# How to implement this multiselect autocomplete react component in Angular?

Tags: autocomplete, angular6, multi-select

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MORy.gif)Need to implement this multi input textbox as the suggestions will come from the database and the entries need to reflect both from back end to front end as its get entered and from front end to backend.

Answer (score 0):

At the front-end part you can use [PrimeNG AutoComplete component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete). It is input component that provides real-time suggestions when being typed. To enable multiple selection you need to add `[multiple]="true"`, it would look like:

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="texts" [suggestions]="results" [multiple]="true"></p-autoComplete>
```

To enable two-way binding in angular you need to use `[(ngModel)]` construction.

Also, you can find some samples using this component at [Github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/src/app/showcase/components/autocomplete)